# Expanding size of 2d Array/ Matrix in Java

Tags: java, arrays, matrix

I have a 2x2 Matrix stored in a 2D Array in java

```
int pixels [][] = new int[2][2];
```

which stores the folowing data in this way

```
{0 2}
{0 2}
```

I am looking for a way for me to expand this matrix for example to a 8x8 Matrix so the result would be something like this:

```
{0  0  0  0  2  2  2  2}
{0  0  0  0  2  2  2  2}
{0  0  0  0  2  2  2  2}
{0  0  0  0  2  2  2  2}
{0  0  0  0  2  2  2  2}
{0  0  0  0  2  2  2  2}
{0  0  0  0  2  2  2  2}
{0  0  0  0  2  2  2  2}
```

Any idea how this could be done using Java?

This is what I've tried so far:

```
int amountToExpand = finalImage.length/2;
     for(int i = 0; i<finalImage.length; i++){
         for(int j = 0; j<finalImage.length; j++){
             if(i < amountToExpand+1){
                 finalImage[i][j]=pixels[][];
             }
         }
     }
```

Comment: so you want to have each array element 4 times and each array as well?

Comment: it's pretty straight forward but what did you try

Comment: @Ramanlfc updated ... thats what I've attempted so far...

Comment: @mtanti95  https://ideone.com/PRj39t

Comment: Lets say my input is now a 4x4 matrix though, how would the code change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key insight is that the cell (i,j) in the final image contains the value of the cell (i/amountToExpand, j/amountToExpand) in the previous image.

This code will work well if the ratio amountToExpand is an integer.

```
int amountToExpand = finalImage.length / pixels.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < finalImage.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < finalImage[i].length; j++) {
                finalImage[i][j] = pixels[i / amountToExpand][j / amountToExpand];
            }
        }
```

Comment: Lets say my input is now a 4x4 matrix though, how would the code change?

Comment: This code would still work ! If the size of the new image is a multiple of the old one, this code will work.
For instance I tried this : 
0  1  2  3  |
4  5  6  7  |
8  9  10 11 |
12 13 14 15 |

And it generated : 
0  0  1  1  2  2  3  3  |
0  0  1  1  2  2  3  3  |
4  4  5  5  6  6  7  7  |
4  4  5  5  6  6  7  7  |
8  8  9  9  10 10 11 11 |
8  8  9  9  10 10 11 11 |
12 12 13 13 14 14 15 15 |
12 12 13 13 14 14 15 15 |

Answer (score 2):

Here you go... expandArray for the expansion and outputArray to display the results of an array for reference.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            int[][] pixels1 = new int[2][2];
            pixels1[0][0] = 1;
            pixels1[0][1] = 2;
            pixels1[1][0] = 3;
            pixels1[1][1] = 4;

            int[][] pixels2 = expandArray(pixels1, 4);

            outputArray(pixels1);
            outputArray(pixels2);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static int[][] expandArray(int[][] arr, int factor) {
        int[][] output = new int[arr.length * factor][arr[0].length * factor];
        for (int i = 0; i < output.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < output[i].length; j++) {
                int orgRow = i / ((arr.length - 1) * factor);
                int orgCol = j / ((arr[0].length - 1) * factor);
                output[i][j] = arr[orgRow][orgCol];
            }
        }

        return output;
    }

    private static void outputArray(int[][] arr) {
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(arr[i][j] + " ");
            }

            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```